# HOW TO: Python: Countdown until matching digits?

Tags: python

So we have to complete a task where we enter a digit from 20-98 (inclusive). The task is to make it so that it stops counting down (or breaks) whenever there's a same-digit number (88,77,66,55,44,33,22). I am able to make it pass tests if I enter 93, but not for other numbers (for ex. 30).

If we enter a digit (for example 93), the output would be:

```
93
92
91
90
89
88
```

is my code so far:

```
x = int(input())


while 20 <= x <= 98:
    print(x, end='\n')
    x -= 1

    if x < 88:
        break
    elif x < 77:
        break
    elif x < 66:
        break
    elif x < 55:
        break
    elif x < 44:
        break
    elif x < 33:
        break
    elif x < 22:
        break
    elif x < 11:
        break

else:
    print("Input must be 20-98")
```

I was wondering how I need to change my code so that it can apply to all numbers, and so I do0n't have to write so many if-else statements for all the possible same-digit numbers.

Comment: The chain of `if ... elif` doesn't really make sense.  All of the `elif` clauses are dead, since if any of them were true, then the `if` itself would be true and the loop would break.  So really it's just a single test, `if x < 88: break`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, but user could type any value between 20-98. So the counting does not always start from a value higher than 88.

Comment: @Asocia The posted code will break at the first `if` test in any of those cases.  It's not checking for a range, it's checking if `x < 88`.  Unless you can provide an example of an integer that's, say, `< 55` but not `< 88`?  I can't.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yeah, you are right about that too. I just try to interpret and guess the _intention_ of OP while writing this code.

Comment: @Asocia Right, clearly that wasn't the *intent*, but it's what the code actually does.  OP needs to learn to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [modulo operator (`%`)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) which yields the remainder from a division.

```
x = int(input())

while 20 <= x <= 98:
    print(x, end='\n')
    if x % 11 == 0:
        break
    x -= 1

else:
    print("Input must be 20-98")
```

Comment: however, this does not print out the 11, 22, 33 , 44 , 55, 66, 77 ,88 number at the end before terminating

Comment: hi @Asocia that worked! however, I have come across a new problem. Now when I input 20, my output becomes: 20
Input must be 20-98 instead of 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11... how can i make it so that it also counts down to 11 even when i input 20?

Comment: It's because the nature of your problem doesn't exactly fit to a `while: ... else: ...` statement. Maybe you can check if the number is in correct range before the loop and then go with `while True:`

Answer (score 0):

```
user_int = int(input())

if 20 <= user_int <=98:

    print(user_int)

    while not user_int % 11 == 0:
        user_int -= 1
        print(user_int)

else:
    print("Input must be 20-98")
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = int(input())

if (x >= 20 and x <= 98):
    while (not (x % 10 == x // 10)):
        print(x)
        x -= 1
    print(x)
else:
    print('Input must be 20-98')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
x = int(input())

while 11 <= x <= 100:
    print(x, end='\n')
    if x % 11 == 0:
        break
    x -= 1

else:
    print("Input must be 11-100") #works for 4.25 DAT210
```